# How to delete text after getstr() c++ ncurses

Tags: c++, c, terminal, ncurses

I have been learning to use the ncurses library and I have come across getstr(). I was wondering how you would erase the text from getstr() on the terminal after the value has already been stored in a variable? I have tried to find the answer on google but no luck!

Basically I want it so when the user presses enter the text will be removed from the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, ncurses has two functions, `gotoxy()` and `getxy()`, which let you jump to every position of the screen and tell you where you are located right know.

Jump to the front of the previous line and call `clrtobot()` to erase everything after the cursor.

**Edit:**

Since you said that clearing the entire window is an option, you can just call `clear()` (also part of the ncurses library).

Answer (score 2):

Not familiar with ncurses, but have you tried moving the cursor, and then overwriting what was typed in?

Comment: No but I was just thinking about making a window in the terminal that holds like an input area and then once the user presses enter it will store the value into a string and then I will use some clear function on that window.